# Android permission dialog not showing

Tags: java, android

In my app I need access to permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.NoteApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.CreateNoteActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:exported="false">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.NoteApp.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

In my code I check If I already have permissions, and if NOT:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_note);

        ImageView imageBack = findViewById(R.id.imageBack);
        imageBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        inputNoteTitle = findViewById(R.id.inputNoteTitle);
        inputNoteText = findViewById(R.id.inputNote);
        textDateTime = findViewById(R.id.textDateTime);
        imageNote = findViewById(R.id.imageNote);

        textDateTime.setText(
                new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
                        .format(new Date())
        );

        ImageView imageSave = findViewById(R.id.imageSave);
        imageSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveNote();
            }
        });

        ImageView imageAddImage = findViewById(R.id.imageAddImage);
        imageAddImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int requestPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                );
                if (requestPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            CreateNoteActivity.this,
                            new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION
                    );
                }
                else {
                    selectImage();
                }
            }
        });
    }

 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_STORAGE_PERMISSION && grantResults.length > 0){
            Log.d("DEBUG", "" + grantResults[0]);
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                selectImage();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

But the permissions dialog never shows, let alone is onRequestPermissionsResult() called.

I don't know why the dialog doesn't show when i use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but it work with READ_MEDIA_IMAGES.

Comment: `In my app I need access to permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` Not if your app runs on a device with Android 13+.

Comment: And READ_MEDIA_IMAGES you will need only for Android 13+ devices.

Comment: Android 11+ needs MANAGE_STORAGE permission instead. And try to use WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. Coz' it has both read and write. No one would just READ something without need of WRITING

Answer (score 0):

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
                isGranted->{
            if (isGranted){
                is_audio_Storage_permitted = true;
            }else{
                is_media_Storage_permitted = false;
                sendToDialog();
            }

});
 public void sendToDialog(){
    AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Alert for Permission")
            .setMessage("Go to setting")
            .setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent mIntent = new Intent();
                    mIntent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                    rIntent.setData(uri);
                    startActivity(rIntent);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                }
            }).show();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).